# Qual a melhor forma de integrar Laravel com angular 2?

Tags: laravel-5, rest, angular

Eu sei criar uma aplicação usando Laravel, e tambem sei como criar uma aplicação usando Angular 2/4. Mas como integrar os 2 ? seria somente criando uma API Laravel e outra aplicação Angular? ou tenho que criar o projeto Angular dentro da pasta Public do projeto laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vai depender como vai estruturar seu projeto, o que ele vai fazer, o quanto de interação ira ter.
Para um projeto médio/grande é bom usar na pasta public e separar da mesma forma que separa os models e controllers do laravel(sem usar o ng-router).
Projeto pequeno fazer separado não é uma ideia ruim.
Mas ainda depende, se vai fazer com distribuição para vários meios(a mesma api usada para o site ser usada em um aplicativo mobile).